# GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1356982504

Tags: linux, debian

I am getting following error while update my source lists

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Reading package lists... Done

W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1356982504

W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

**How to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 13):

To find any expired repository keys and their IDs, use apt-key as follows:

```
  apt-key list | grep expired
```

You will get a result similar to the following:

```
  pub   4096R/BE1DB1F1 2011-03-29 [expired: 2014-03-28]
```

The key ID is the bit after the / i.e. BE1DB1F1 in this case.

To update the key, run

```
  sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net BE1DB1F1
```

Comment: I will have to execute this command on my server. It wont break anything right? I am newbie in the field of linux that's why asking

Comment: No, it will just renew expired keys only

Comment: Do you have debian-archive-keyring version 2010.08.28~lenny1
installed?

Comment: Ensure that the system time is correct.  Manually upgrade or install the
"debian-archive-keyring" so that it is the correct version.  Then
"apt-get update" again and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Try with this :wget --no-check-certificate https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys/archive-key-6.0.asc
&& apt-key add archive-key-6.0.asc
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
apt-get update

Comment: Looks like keys.gnupg.net is no longer a working address: pgp.mit.edu worked in 2022.

Comment: Another working address instead of `keys.gnupg.net ` is `keyserver.ubuntu.com `. [source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/unable-to-connect-to-keys-gnupg-net-838576/)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and I just change the system date

```
date --set 2008-01-01
```

then try to update

```
apt-get update
```

Comment: You are being downvoted because this solution looks really bad at first glance but when one need to maintain some old living-corpse (like old Debian Jessie based box in 2020 :) then time travel may be the cheapest way to go (if you can do that). Otherwise one will spend a lot of time looking for i.e. solution to convince old apt to pass `KEYEXPIRED` (yet to be found) etc which may not necessary be worth your time. If you can, shutdown all services, put your box to runlevel 1, time travel, apt update, restore the date, cross your fingers and reboot/restart/whatever.

Comment: Hey, this is a GREAT solution for me because I'm creating a throw-away virtual machine based on lenny to debug some code that has to work with an old 2.6 driver. I will have no need for this VM in a week, and it won't be on the internet. I have nothing to lose by doing this, and time to lose by doing anything more complex.

Comment: Honesty great solution almost no one suggest that even in debian mailing list (I search a lot) , and for security concerns I need this in closed system no network access, I need it to get old `256 MB` `32bit` PC to get works, and thank god Debian existing they server old repository opposite to most Linux distro (even Ubuntu dropped their old Dist servers)

Comment: Turning back time was a fantastic solution that worked for me when trying to setup QEMU with an ancient version of Debian (Jessie).

Comment: This is a viable solution, but unfortunately won't work if you are using a VPS

Answer (score 9):

At the end any of this answers solve my issue.

What I did is recheck for the latest available sources. In my case

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free 

###### Debian Update Repos
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free 
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-proposed-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-proposed-updates main contrib non-free
```

I generate them using this website. https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ Debian Source generator.

Then I update the keys in the repo.

```
apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
apt-key update
```

Then again try to update

```
apt-get update
```

That will probably fix the issue.

```
Fetched 67.5 kB in 2min 0s (560 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

If you still problems with some keys follow the next steps per key.

You need to add the key manually from another server. 
In this case the missing key is 55BE302B

So you have to do:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  55BE302B
gpg -a --export 55BE302B | sudo apt-key add -
```

It will import the key and then you add them to the sources.

```
root@XXX:~# gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  55BE302B
gpg: requesting key 55BE302B from hkp server pgpkeys.mit.edu
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 55BE302B: public key "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (5.0/lenny) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
root@XXX:~# gpg -a --export 55BE302B | sudo apt-key add -     
OK
```

I hope this help anyone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this issue is to, refresh GPG keys so that local keyrings can successfully verify the signatures

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y debian-archive-keyring && apt-get clean
```